# How to use getElementById on a link to pick up textfield value

Tags: javascript, php, html, url-rewriting

I want use document.getElementById('YourElementId') to pick up the Textfield value and then send it to another page called request.php as URL parameter.

Example, if i type (3) on the Textfiled and click submit, the Link will pick up the form variable  as url parameter just like the folowing (.../requst.php?=id=3) Onsubmit.

Bellow is my textfield and the submit link/button but it doesnt work. Someone please help me.

```
<input name="consigno" type="text" id="YourElementId" value="3">
<a href="" onclick="this.href='remote.php?nav='+document.getElementById('YourElementId').value">ENTER</a>
```

Comment: that does not seem to be the best approach - you limit yourself by insisting upon using an ID which must be known by the javascript function and which, by definition, must be unique. Perhaps if you shared more of the code and explain the objective a better approach might become apparent?! You could, if the HTML structure follows the meagre snippet shown here simply use `event.previousElementSibling` - from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling)

Comment: also - clicking the hyperlink seems to only set the href attribute rather than redirect the user to the chosen page

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this by using html form. This will do same thing.

```
<form method="GET" action="remote.php">
    <input name="nav" id="YourElementId" type="text" value="3">
    <input type="submit" value="ENTER">
</form>
```